# How do electrons move across depletion region in npn transistor?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, electronics

Concerning the base-collector barrier, the electrons coming from the emitter move through the barrier using diffusion mainly and drift. Does carrier injection happen as a result of these two mechanisms which leads it to be collected by the collector?
I have some confusion here.